# Using Arduino Uno R3 + Ethernet Module, how to control current pass to Lamps?

Tags: power-supply, light, solid-state-relay

I have Arduino Uno R3 and Arduino Ethernet Shield V5.

What's missing in order to control 6+ lights (bulbs) from my home? Those are connected to 220V AC.

My idea is to send a packet via ethernet that has an order for example: "Turn on light 1", "Turn on light 4".

Maybe a relays module?

Obviously the power cables for lights will come from the controller. I want to test now so I can deploy it in real house lights.

Sorry if I am not being too much specific, I am starting to learn.

Comment: You'll want to search for a "relay shield" or "relay board".  And be careful, mains voltage can be very dangerous.

Comment: "power cables for lights will come from the controller"  No, the power for the lights will NOT come from the Arduino.  The Arduino will send a small signal to a relay that will power the lights.

Comment: @mikeY yes, that's true. Is this OK? http://articulo.mercadolibre.com.ar/MLA-482072259-modulo-de-8-relee-relay-arduino-pic-_JM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe a relays module?

Yes exactly.  $10 or $15 US.

[http://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-8-CH-8-Channel-Relay-Module/dp/B0057OC5WK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057OC5WK)

http://www.ebay.com/itm/8-Channel-5V-Relay-Module-Board-Shield-for-Arduino-PIC-AVR-MCU-DSP-ARM-/390594938127